# Sum of cubes divisible by $10^6$

Tags: divisibility, decimal-expansion

Is there a 6-digit number $\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_6}$ such that the sum of cubes
$$\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_6}^3+\overline{a_6a_5\dots a_1}^3$$ is divisible by $10^6$?

We have the usual sum of cubes factorization
$$\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_6}^3+\overline{a_6a_5\dots a_1}^3=(\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_6}+\overline{a_6a_5\dots a_1})(\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_6}^2+\overline{a_1a_2\dots a_6}\cdot\overline{a_6a_5\dots a_1}+\overline{a_6a_5\dots a_1}^2)$$

If we make the first sum divisible by $10$, then by case checking we find that the second sum cannot be divisible by $10$. But then we cannot make the first sum divisible by $10^6$ either.

Comment: [Python](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@5@WX6SQqZCZp1CUmJeeqmFooKVlqgMizTStuDgz0xQ0MrW0jBW0gUpKNIpLijQyNaOtrHQNYzWBwpoKqgoaEMUKtrYKBkAdnAVFIJWZmv//AwA) gives me `520175
521075
528975
529875
570125
571025
578925
579825`

Comment: Use the binomial expansion.  One thing a6^3 + a2^3 must be divide by 10,  and a5a6^3 + a2a1^3 must be div by 100 and so on.